# Android KitKat not showing Toast once the App goes to background

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, toast

I am running a service from my Android test app, which needs to show toast from counter value which is continuously increasing in a service.

Its starting well, and showing the toast. But, **once I press back/home button to keep the app in background, the toast stops showing. When I again bring the app to foreground, again the toast started visible**.

This problem happens sin Kitkat. But in JellyBeans and below, its working fine.

Here is my manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rtrgroup.mysms"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>   

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity
            android:name="com.rtrgroup.mysms.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>  

        <service android:name="com.rtrgroup.mysms.MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my MainActivity.java file.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
}
}
```

Here is my service code, MyService.java:

```
package com.rtrgroup.mysms;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MyService extends Service {
    Handler handler;
    int count  = 0;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(test, 1000);

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    Runnable test = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TOAST count = " + String.valueOf(count), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            count++;
            handler.postDelayed(test, 5000);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So, how to make toast visible always, even the app is in background and the service is running? Please explain.

Comment: Why not use a notification? That is the correct way to do it..

Answer (score 0):

if you want to detect when the user put your app in background , override this method

```
  @Override
public void onTrimMemory(int level) {
    super.onTrimMemory(level);
    switch (level) {
        case ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN:
            // do your magic here 
            break;
    }

}
```

check the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN

also you can start your service in "foreground" mode  for this check 
[Show notification from background started service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418642/show-notification-from-background-started-service/22418754#22418754)

or you can show a notification instead a toast.